# Android SQlite delete Column not deleted in AlertDialogBox Item

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Any one Help me for delete SQlite delete column which collection(Column data) is Saved in DataBase.

Sometimes its works great but In sometime its not delete by one click.
My Code :-

```
DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);

SQLiteDatabas db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

db.delete(dbh.TABLE_CONTACTS, dbh.KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] { idList.get(which) });
db.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: it may be idList.get(which) has no value

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your UI, once you have rendered something to the UI, it stays in the UI and is not connected to any background-data